# FunctionDomain and FindInstance problem

Tags: functions, complex, findinstance

I have some functions including many real parameters as follows:

For example,

```
f[x_] := (2*I*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[Subscript[a, 3]]*
    Sqrt[-((y*z*(-1 + k*Subscript[β, 2])*(k*p + ϕ + k^2*Subscript[β, 1] - k*ϕ*Subscript[β, 2]))/
       (Subscript[a, 3]*(Subscript[β, 1] + p*Subscript[β, 2] + k*Subscript[β, 1]*Subscript[β, 2] - ϕ*Subscript[β, 2]^2)))]*
    Sqrt[Subscript[β, 1] + p*Subscript[β, 2] + k*Subscript[β, 1]*Subscript[β, 2] - ϕ*Subscript[β, 2]^2])/
   (((-E^((-x)*Sqrt[-(((-1 + k*Subscript[β, 2])*(k*p + ϕ + k^2*Subscript[β, 1] - k*ϕ*Subscript[β, 2]))/
            (Subscript[β, 1] + p*Subscript[β, 2] + k*Subscript[β, 1]*Subscript[β, 2] - ϕ*Subscript[β, 2]^2))]))*y + 
     E^(x*Sqrt[-(((-1 + k*Subscript[β, 2])*(k*p + ϕ + k^2*Subscript[β, 1] - k*ϕ*Subscript[β, 2]))/
           (Subscript[β, 1] + p*Subscript[β, 2] + k*Subscript[β, 1]*Subscript[β, 2] - ϕ*Subscript[β, 2]^2))])*z)*
    Sqrt[b + 2*k*q + 2*k*r - b*k*Subscript[β, 2] - 2*k^2*q*Subscript[β, 2] - 2*k^2*r*Subscript[β, 2]]);
```

I want to find appropriate parameters satisfying `f(x):R->R.` I think we can use `FunctionDomain` and then `FindInstance`.

The commands work for my other problems. But in here, `FunctionDomain` gives `False`.

```
dom = FunctionDomain[f[x], {x,b, k, p, q, r, y, z, ϕ, Subscript[a, 3], Subscript[β, 1], Subscript[β, 2]}, Reals] 
FindInstance[dom, {x,b, k, p, q, r, y, z, ϕ, Subscript[a, 3], Subscript[β, 1], Subscript[β, 2]} ∈ Reals, 3]
```

But when I substitute the following parameters into the f[x], I get a real-valued function.

```
params = {b -> 7/8, k -> 7/8, p -> 7/8, q -> 7/8, r -> 7/8,
          y -> -(7/8), z -> 7/8, ϕ -> 7/8, Subscript[a, 3] -> 1, 
          Subscript[β, 1] -> 7/8, Subscript[β, 2] -> 7/8};

Simplify[f[x] /. params]
```

If `FunctionDomain` doesn't work for this kind of problem, how to find the domain of the function given in the post and then how to find appropriate parameters satisfying `f(x):R->R.`

Comment: Isn't this mentioned in the Possible Issues explicitly or am I misunderstanding something? "All subexpressions of f need to be real-valued for a point to belong to the real domain of f" https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html

Comment: If `FunctionDomain` doesn't work for this kind of problem, how to find the domain of the function given in the post and then how to find appropriate parameters satisfying f(x):R->R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you consider a function of many variables

```
f[x_, Subscript[\[Beta], 1] _, Subscript[\[Beta], 2] _,  Subscript[a, 3] _, y_, z_, k_, 
\[Phi]_, p_, r_, q_] := (2*I*Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[Subscript[a, 3]]*
 Sqrt[-((y*
       z*(-1 + k*Subscript[\[Beta], 2])*(k*p + \[Phi] + 
         k^2*Subscript[\[Beta], 1] - 
         k * Subscript[\[Beta], 2]))/(Subscript[a, 
        3]*(Subscript[\[Beta], 1] + p*Subscript[\[Beta], 2] + 
         k*Subscript[\[Beta], 1]*Subscript[\[Beta], 2] - \[Phi]*
          Subscript[\[Beta], 2]^2)))]*
 Sqrt[Subscript[\[Beta], 1] + p*Subscript[\[Beta], 2] + 
   k*Subscript[\[Beta], 1]*Subscript[\[Beta], 2] - \[Phi]*
    Subscript[\[Beta], 
      2]^2])/(((-E^((-x)*
         Sqrt[-(((-1 + k*Subscript[\[Beta], 2])*(k*p + \[Phi] + 
                k^2*Subscript[\[Beta], 1] - 
                k*\[Phi]*
                Subscript[\[Beta], 2]))/(Subscript[\[Beta], 1] + 
               p*Subscript[\[Beta], 2] + 
               k*Subscript[\[Beta], 1]*
                Subscript[\[Beta], 2] - \[Phi]*
                Subscript[\[Beta], 2]^2))]))*y + 
   E^(x*Sqrt[-(((-1 + k*Subscript[\[Beta], 2])*(k*p + \[Phi] + 
               k^2*Subscript[\[Beta], 1] - 
               k*\[Phi]*
                Subscript[\[Beta], 2]))/(Subscript[\[Beta], 1] + 
             p*Subscript[\[Beta], 2] + 
             k*Subscript[\[Beta], 1]*
              Subscript[\[Beta], 2] - \[Phi]*
              Subscript[\[Beta], 2]^2))])*z)*
 Sqrt[b + 2*k*q + 2*k*r - b*k*Subscript[\[Beta], 2] - 
   2*k^2*q*Subscript[\[Beta], 2] - 
   2*k^2*r*Subscript[\[Beta], 2]]);
```

and ask when this function as a function of `x` is real-valued for every real value of `x`. The answer can be derived as follows.

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, x \[Element] Reals,  f[x, Subscript[\[Beta], 1], 
Subscript[\[Beta], 2], Subscript[a, 3], 
y, z, k, \[Phi], p, r, q] \[Element] Reals], Reals]
```

> `True`

It means that for all  real values of the parameters the answer is affirmative.

Comment: A simpler example of such sort is `Sqrt[-(I*a*x - 1)*(I*a*x + 1)]` which defines a real-valued function for every real value of parameter `a`.

Comment: Please, explain the downvote. What is incorrect in my answer? In the other case such behavior does not make a good impression about this forum.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.  You said that for all real values of the parameters the  function is real-valued. What about `params2 = {b -> 1, k -> 2, p -> 7/8, q -> 7/8, r -> 7/8, y -> -(7/8), 
   z -> 7/8, \[Phi] -> 7/8, Subscript[a, 3] -> 1, 
   Subscript[\[Beta], 1] -> 7/8, Subscript[\[Beta], 2] -> 7/8};
Simplify[f[x] /. params2] // Im`

Comment: @Eric_Jansen:  This results in `(Sqrt[3/199] E^(2 I Sqrt[21/61] x) Sqrt[49 - 8 2*7/8])/(1 + E^(
 4 I Sqrt[21/61] x))==(Sqrt[3/199] *Sqrt[49 - 8 2*7/8])/Cos[2 * Sqrt[21/61] x]` which is real valued. See my simpler example in my comment. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need and don't hurry to downvote.

Comment: For the user's convenience, here is the result in the standard math notation $$ \frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{199}} \sqrt{49-8 2\text{*}\frac{7}{8}} e^{2 i \sqrt{\frac{21}{61}} x}}{1+e^{4 i \sqrt{\frac{21}{61}} x}}.$$

Comment: There is a typo in `f[...]` of my code. In line 6 it should be `*` instead of `**`.

Comment: The typo is fixed.

Comment: Thank you. How to find the domain of the function `f[x]` in the post?   `FunctionDomain` doesn't work.

Comment: What function do you mean and in which variable? Your `f[x_]`?

Comment: Yes, I want to find the domain of the function `f[x]` in the post.

Comment: If so, its domain over the reals depends on parameters. As examples show, the domain may be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R$   minus a discrete periodic set.

Comment: I honestly don't see why the downvote since the answer is accepted by the author of the OP. It does not make sense to me, and I think it's gonna be confusing for other users. It's a (+1) from, because as far as I can see there are no issues here.